# Is there any OSM based (or open source) online tool to draw circles on a map?

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm looking for online tools to draw circles on a map (with accurate center and radius). By accurate edit, I mean:

- edit center GPS coordinates
- edit radius (in meters)

I tested https://www.mapdevelopers.com/draw-circle-tool.php. It does the trick, as I can draw circles with accurate center and radius, but I find the UI quite confusing.  Also, I'd prefer an open source project (so I can participate) based on OpenStreetMap.

I had the idea of using GeoJSON (on 
http://geojson.io for example), but there's no circle feature [yet](https://github.com/geojson/geojson-spec/issues/1) in GeoJSON
- I tested https://geoman.io; it's OSM based but I can't edit circles center and radius

Is there any other tool to draw circles over a map (OSM preferred) and edit center and radius ?

Visual example (from https://www.mapdevelopers.com/draw-circle-tool.php):

[image: 1]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what you mean by "circle" -- In the GIS realm, a true circle might not look like one, and a figure that looks like a circle might not be one. The spatial reference ID of your map is needed.

Comment: @Vince ok, done !

Comment: Does it need to be able to create [geodesic circles](https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0111/geodesic.html)?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I had no idea of what is a "geodesic circle". But the circles I've to do have very little radius compared to Earth radius (< 100km) so I presume I should answer: no